# How do i secure my html element value?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am developing an eCommerce website where user can select main product and also some extra accessories as per product.Also calculating total price (main product + accessories) to show it to user.

For now i am storing product price,individual accessories price and total price  in hidden html input tag but it is easily accessible from inspect window.

How do i make it more secure?

Comment: Nope you can't secure it from client side instead you need to handle your calculations at your server side

Comment: don't worry , no one can do anything with that price value !!!

Comment: Why does it matter ? Its just what the user sees it should not affect your backend. In the backend you should than calculate the finale price, never ever ever in the fron end :)

Comment: some guys mess with my system and change the total amount of product which i am passing it to payment gateway

Comment: in that case, don't pass that value from the client directly to the gateway. Use the server to check it before passing it on. You should be able to retrieve and/or derive the correct price(s) from your DB, not rely on what the client sends. Nothing on the client is secure. Everyone's browser is a fully-fledged IDE. You don't even necessarily need a browser in order to make a mess. Something like Postman could do the job, depending how badly the application in question is designed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Securing Hidden you can also apply `encryption and hashing` to hidden input fields,

> - Hash the original value
> - Encrypt the original value
> - Send the encrypted value along with the hash digest
> - Upon receiving back the data, decrypt the encryption, hash the result and compare it to the received hash digest to ensure the value
>     remained unchanged

Reference From : [Securing HTML hidden input fields](http://yavkata.co.uk/weblog/php/securing-html-hidden-input-fields-using-encryption-and-hashing/)

Answer (score 2):

The value stored on the page or inside a cookie should be just for the users view, it shouldn't be used for backend validation since anything stored on the users machine could potentially be changed by the user.

As others have stated, you should be validating the price with your backend software at checkout.

Answer (score 2):

Hi there is one rule nothing in client side is secure. So once you will display something to user than this is not secure. If you have something that has to be secure (some client ids certificate, tokens ... ) You have to handle this on backend.

You can just hide this information, but on backend you have to always validate inputs. User can do fake request, change values etc.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of storing the **product price**, you should store **product id** and than in your back end get the price of that particular id selected by the user, do the sum or any other calculation which needs to be done and save in database.